# Scrapy provides ambiguous results in pagination

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

I have created a scrapy spider which do pagination. Using the same script with different link from the same website and pagination was stopped by "Filtered offsite request". Turning on the feature "dont_filter" in scrapy Request runs into infity loop over the page. Wondering how a script could provide different results without any changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide your code so we could be more helpful.

Make sure you have only the domain in the field `allowed_domains` of your spider. For example:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com'] # Don't use 'https://example.com/some/path/here'
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/some/path/here']
```

Obviously, the domain in `allowed_domains` must match the domains you are creating requests to.

You can also remove this attribute entirely. More details on `allowed_domains` [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains).

Comment: thank you for the idea, I couldn't believe this could cause an so strage issue